# Attempting to get the text from a certain part of a website using lxml.html

Tags: python, html, lxml, lxml.html

I have some current Python code that is supposed to get the HTML from a certain part of a website, using the xpath of where the HTML tag is located.

```
def wordorigins(word):
    pageopen = lxml.html.fromstring("http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/" + str(word))
    pbody = pageopen.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/main/article/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[1]")
    etybody = lxml.html.fromstring(pbody)
    etytxt = etybody.xpath('text()')
    etytxt = etytxt.replace("<em>", "")
    etytxt = etytxt.replace("</em>", "")
    return etytxt
```

This code returns this error about expecting a string or a buffer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mott.py", line 47, in <module>
    print wordorigins(x)
  File "mott.py", line 30, in wordorigins
    etybody = lxml.html.fromstring(pbody)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 866, in fromstring
    is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xpath()` method returns a *list of results*, `fromstring()` expects a string.

But, you don't need to reparse the part of the document. Just use what you've already found:

```
def wordorigins(word):
    pageopen = lxml.html.fromstring("http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/" + str(word))
    pbody = pageopen.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/main/article/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/p[1]")[0]
    etytxt = pbody.text_content()
    etytxt = etytxt.replace("<em>", "")
    etytxt = etytxt.replace("</em>", "")
    return etytxt
```

Note that I'm using `text_content()` method instead of the `xpath("text()")`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [@alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe)'s answer, the `xpath()` method returns list of matched elements in this case, hence the error when you tried to pass the list to `lxml.html.fromstring()`. Another thing to note is, that neither XPath's `text()` function nor `lxml`'s `text_content()` method would ever return string containing tag such as `<em></em>`. They automatically strips tags if any, so the two `replace()` lines are not needed. You can simply use `text_content()` or XPath's `string()` function (instead of `text()`) :

```
......
# either of the following lines should be enough
etytxt = pbody[0].xpath('string()')
etytxt = pbody[0].text_content()
```